# How could I animate a border on a toggled class with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

As the title suggests. When I click on something, a class gets added to it with a border on the bottom. I just want that to fade in (and out if possible). I'm not sure if I need to do this with JS or if it can be done with CSS.

So far here's what I've tried - at least with CSS.

```css
.selector {
  width: auto;
  height: 30%;
  width: auto;
  height: 50%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}

/*TOGGLE CLASS*/

.active {
  border-bottom: 1px #a0a0a0 solid;
  transition: border-bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<span class="selector"
            ><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="quote(0)"
              ><img
                src="..."
                alt=""/></a
          ></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `[transtion][1]` property in CSS to set the transition-time (and other cool things).

**In your case** you can for example add a class. We can name it `.transition-3s`. Then in your CSS file you can declare this class as follows:

```
.transition-3s {
    transition: 3s;
}
```

**EDIT**

Do not apply this on your `.active` class, as this will result in it only using transition when "deactivating" the toggle.

Comment: Thanks! this actually worked well with the other animation effect (shrinking the img a little), but did nothing to actually fade in and out the border which just appeared instantly while the other animation eased in. Just out of curiosity, I tried using a box shadow to mimic the border and now it works just as I had originally intended!

Answer (score 0):

You can use inputs to do it. In this case, the best practice is to use a "checkbox" type and with the subclass of ":checked" you can use it like an added class, here you have the example of how it would look in your code:

```css
#toggle {
  display: none; //To hide it
}

#toggle:checked ~ span img { //select the element to toggle
  //As you see, when you press the lable, this is triggered
  border-bottom: 1px #a0a0a0 solid;
  transition: border-bottom 0.5s ease-in-out;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.selector {
  width: auto;
  height: 30%;
  width: auto;
  height: 50%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
```

```html
<input id="toggle" type="checkbox">
<label for="toggle">This is the text that will toggle the "class"</label>
<span class="selector">
  <img src="..." alt="">
</span>
```

You can use the span as a label, just mess around with it.
And for animate it, just use the attribute transition to make it smooth:

```css
#toggle:checked ~ span .active {
  border-bottom: 1px #a0a0a0 solid;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  //not in here
}
.active { //or img
 transition: border-bottom 500ms ease-in-out; //use it here to make it more clear
}
```

Hope it helped, ask for any doubt.